# How do I unpack a TBN File, meant for flashing a phone?

Tags: firmware, file-format, unpacking

I have a file used to flash new firmware to a phone and I need to unpack it into smaller files that are contained in the "TBN" file. The smaller files that are contained in the TBN file are common files used when flashing phones that usually come as separate files so I know about them but I don't know how to extract them from this TBN file.

How do I go about unpacking this file?

Comment: Can you provide a hexdump of the first 64 bytes or so?

Answer (score 2):

It might be a standard file format, just renamed. Try [binwalk](http://binwalk.org/) on it.